# Angular Unit Testing - Verify emitted value from an observable using marble testing

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular-test

I'm creating some unit tests for an Angular application that I have. I have managed to test services that make HTTP calls without any problems. I now moved to a different kind of service, which is shown below.

**Code**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable, Subject } from 'rxjs';

import { UICoupon } from '../models';

@Injectable()
export class ClaimCouponService {
    hasClaimedCoupons = false;

    claimedCoupons: UICoupon[] = [];

    onClaimCoupons: Observable<UICoupon[]>;

    private couponsUpdate: Subject<UICoupon[]> = new Subject<UICoupon[]>();

    constructor() {
        this.onClaimCoupons = this.couponsUpdate.asObservable();
    }

    claimCoupon(coupon: UICoupon) {
        if (!coupon.claimed) {
            coupon.claimed = true;
            this.claimedCoupons.push(coupon);
        }
        this.hasClaimedCoupons = true;
        this.couponsUpdate.next(this.claimedCoupons);
    }
}
```

I have managed to test the logic for this service using the "Subscribe / Assert pattern". Using the below code:

```
...

it('should claim a coupon', (done) => {
    claimCouponsService.onClaimCoupons
        .subscribe(claimedCoupons => {
            expect(claimedCoupons).toEqual([mockData[0]]);
            done();
        });

    claimCouponsService.claimCoupon(mockData[0]);
});
```

The above works well, however I was researching and I was curious about Marble Testing. I've read a few articles and I like how the logic is structured in the test. I've tried to replicate the above test with Marble Testing, but in my case I couldn't find a way to verify what is emitted from the service after the `claimCoupon(...)` function is run.

```
let scheduler: TestScheduler;
let claimCouponsService: ClaimCouponsService;

...

it('should claim a coupon', (done) => {
    const expectedObservable = claimCouponsService.onClaimCoupons;

    scheduler.run(runHelpers => {
        claimCouponsService.claimCoupon(mockData[0]);

        const expectedMarble = '^a|';
        const expectedData = { a: [mockData[0]] };

        runHelpers.expectObservable(expectedObservable)
            .toBe(expectedMarble, expectedData);
    });
});
```

I'm pretty sure that this is possible, but I have some kind of mistake in my test - or haven't really understood the way marble testing works. The above results in an error `Expected $.length = 0 to equal 1.` which I think means that the observable didn't get any values. I know the test I wrote does run successfully, however I'm curious to see how Marble Testing can be used.

Comment: I think your `expectedMarble` should be just `'a'` because `|` means a complete notification (but you never complete `couponsUpdate`) and `^` means point of subscription which is used only by `TestScheduler.expectSubscriptions()`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. To be honest I've been trying lots of different versions of the marble to see if something works. I just tried `'a'` however no luck. I'm researching to try to see what's the problem.

Comment: I'm looking at your code again and you're calling `next()` inside `claimCoupon` and using `expectObservable` after that so it never receives any emission. I'm afraid there's no nice way to test this with marbles.

Comment: @DanielGrima check out this [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60081765/853678). You can subscribe to a cold observable given to you by the test scheduler and call your method when it emits